# Can I set overflow: hidden but still show a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to disable scrolling for when there's a popup, but I hate how the entire page changes size when you add/remove the scrollbar. Is there a way to disable scrolling without hiding the scrollbar?

Kind of like when you set overflow:scroll to an element that doesn't have enough content to scroll: it still shows the scrollbar but it's disabled.

```
//when popup is open, disable scroll on body
body.popupOpen {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the overflow (the scroll bar) is on the body element then add an overlay that will simply cover the body and its scroll bar when the popup is shown.

Here is a simplified example with only the overlay where you cannot scroll:

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100vh; /* no more than the height of the viewport*/
}

html {
  overflow: hidden; /* This one is important to avoid the propagation */
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.content {
  min-height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">

</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, but you can set 'hidden' and create a element to simulate the scrollbar, but why would you do this, it only makes the user confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div that fullfils the whole page view, and just make it transparent, this way you can just enable/disable the div scroll to mantain a scrollbar:

```css
.theDivInactive { 
   background: none;
   pointer_events: none;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

and switch the class when the popup is on the screen:

  .theDivActive { 
   background: none;
   pointer_events: none;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: scroll;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue the same way bootstrap does. Just in case other methods doesn't work for you, here's the JS trick to calculate scrollbar width for a given browser. Then on modal open, you can set the padding-right to body element:

```js
const documentWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const scrollbarWidth = Math.abs(window.innerWidth - documentWidth);
document.body.style.paddingRight = `${scrollbarWidth}px`;
```

Note: this will only work **well** if you set `overflow-y: scroll` to popup bg or put the popup over the white strap that was created as the side effect of the `padding-right` property.

Note 2: If elements are positioned absolutely relative to body width, they will still "jump" so you need to add padding to them as well or wrap them with div that has `position: relative`